# I'm making a post call to the server using two different method but I'm getting two different responses

Tags: angularjs

I have made server side call using two different methods

```
Demo.create({id: id}, function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        //{"0":"h","1":"t","2":"t","3":"p","4":"s","5":":","6":"/","7":"/","8":"d","9":"e","10":"m","11":"o","12":".","13":"d","14":"o","15":"c","16":"u","17":"s","18":"i","19":"g","20":"n","21":".","22":"n","23":"e","24":"t","25":"/","26":"M","27":"e","28":"m","29":"b","30":"e","31":"r","32":"/","33":"S","34":"t","35":"a","36":"r","37":"t","38":"I","39":"n","40":"S","41":"e","42":"s","43":"s","44":"i","45":"o","46":"n","47":".","48":"a","49":"s","50":"p","51":"x","52":"?","53":"t","54":"=","55":"6","56":"3","57":"c","58":"3","59":"e","60":"7","61":"7","62":"f","63":"-","64":"e","65":"1","66":"b","67":"8","68":"-","69":"4","70":"b","71":"b","72":"4","73":"-","74":"8","75":"5","76":"0","77":"1","78":"-","79":"5","80":"8","81":"8","82":"1","83":"1","84":"2","85":"8","86":"2","87":"4","88":"9","89":"c","90":"0"}
    });
```

I'm supposed to get url from server but I'm getting above

```
$http.post('/sign/23423', {
       })
         .success(function(respond){
             console.log(respond); // getting the url as expected
       })
         .error(function(){
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  .success(function(respond){
         console.log(JSON.stringify(respond)); // CHANGE THIS LINE
   })
```

```
Demo.create({id: id}, function(data){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));      // OR THIS LINE
});
```